# How to detect/prevent a counter overflow

Tags: c, embedded, overflow

I have a counter on a 16 bits field that is incremented/decremented over the time by a hardware peripheral.
I sample its value periodically to sum the difference into a 32bits field.

My problem is to detect the overflow/underflow of the 16 bits field when computing the difference.

Let's take an example:
At sample n-1, the counter value Vn-1 is 65530.
As sample n, the counter value Vn is 4.
The counter has been incremented by 10. But the difference (Vn - Vn-1), will be something like 65529 (not sure of the exact value).

The only way I found to detect this overflow is to compare the difference value to a fixed value greater than the max increment (I choose 10000).
Do you know a solution to manage this overflow without comparing to this subjective value?

Here is a code example:

```
static sint32 overallCount = 0;
sint32 diff;
static sint16 previousValue = 0;
sint16 currentValue;

currentValue = sampleValue();

diff = ((sint32) currentValue) - previousValue;
if(diff > 10000) {
    diff -= 65536;
} else if ((-diff) > 10000) {
    diff += 65536;
}

overallCount += diff;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My previous answer had some mistakes so I've rewritten it, but the idea is the same, use unsigned types correctly.

Make currentValue and previousValue both unsigned integers of the chosen size (e.g. uint16_t). Then merely subtract them. Since the difference will be implicitly promoted to `int` if `int` is a larger type than `uint16_t`, you'll need to cast or implicitly convert the result back to `uint16_t`. So:

```
static uint16_t previousValue;
uint16_t currentValue = sampleValue();
uint16_t diff = currentValue - previousValue;
```

This makes use of the implicit conversion in the assignment, but you could cast if you like.

Comment: Could you explain your statement? Making the computation in signed or unsigned will only transfer the overflow from 0/65535 to -32768/32768.

Comment: Sorry, hopefully it's better now.

Comment: I never saw this implicit type conversion from unsigned to signed! currentValue - previousValue will always be done as unsigned and in case of an overflow of currentValue the diff won't be the effective difference

Comment: In C, **all arithmetic is promoted at least to `int`**. that's why you see wrong results if you don't cast or assign back to a `uint16_t`.

Comment: Ok understood! you were right :) The only thing i need to do is to cast the diff in sint16 for the sum in the 32-bit field to manage underflows.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few ideas for you:

1. Do the addition in a 32-bit field, and verify that the result will fit into the 16-bit field afterwards.
2. Test whether the old value's high bit changed as a result of the addition.
3. Do the addition in assembly, and check the carry flag afterwards.

Comment: About your first point, the addition is already done over 32-bit field. I need to keep a global counter that does not overflow. I will consider your 2 other ideas.

Comment: I thought you said your current value was overflowing? I am suggesting that do something like `int32 temp = currentValue & 0xffff; temp += newValue; if (temp > 65535) overflow! else currentValue = (int16)temp;`

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to just keep track of the overflow count.  Using uint16_t for the values,

```
if (currentValue < previousValue) overflows++;
```

Then to get a 32-bit value, you combine overflows with currentValue.

`result = currentValue | (overflows << 16);`

Comment: This does not work because the counter goes in both directions (increment and decrement). So currentValue can be less the previous value without overflowing.

Answer (score -1):

You could try using a [Kalman filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter) to detect the overflow.

Comment: I am looking for a simple solution that does not require much overhead because I am running with limited processing resources. But thank you for this idea!

Comment: This was a joke. Right? :D Because "Kalman filter solves everything"